# Expanding and simplifying polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My teacher gave me a worksheet and it says to expand the polynomial and then simplify it.

Question:

$$(6h + k - 2)(2h - 3) - (4h - 3k)^2$$

I actually tried doing the question but the answer I got is:

$$12h^2 - 38h + 2kh - 12k + 6$$

I don't know if it is right. If I got it wrong, it would be awesome to show your work or explain it.

Comment: $$-4 h^2+26 h k-22 h-9 k^2-3 k+6$$

Comment: How did you get that answer.

Comment: WolframAlpha${}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(6h + k - 2)(2h - 3) - (4h - 3k)^{2} &= 2h(6h + k - 2) - 3(6h + k - 2) - (16h^{2} - 24hk + 9k^{2}) \\
&= 12h^{2} + 2hk - 4h - 18h - 3k + 6 - (16h^{2} - 24hk + 9k^{2}) \\
&= -4h^{2} + 26hk - 22h - 3k - 9k^{2} + 6
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets break the problem into 2 parts:
$(6h+k−2)(2h−3)$ and $−(4h−3k)2.$

Expand the first part and you will get:
$$12h^2+2hk-22h-3k+6$$

Expand the second part and you will get:
$$-16 h^2+24 h k-9 k^2$$

Then simply combine like terms in both expressions together and the answer is:

$$-4 h^2+26 h k-22 h-9 k^2-3 k+6$$

---

If you don't know how to do the expansion here is a quick summary:

ex:
$$= (x-3)(y-4)$$
$$= x(y-4)-3(y-4)$$
$$= xy-4x -3y-12$$

You can apply the same principle to your problem. In the future if you just need a quick answer check. WolframAlpha has an amazing computation engine.